# ASP.NET @Html.DropDownListFor() selected value is set to true but returns false when submitted to the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am lost on what is happening when I submit the code. I'm trying to get the correct value of the employee and dealer `@Html.DropDownListFor()` based on what is selected at submission. I set the values to true in the `[HttpGet]` method in the controller and when passed to the view are set and show correctly.But when I submit the form I am getting `false` in the `[HttpPost]` method in the controller. Here is the controller, view, viewModel code.

**Controller**

```
      [HttpGet]
      public ActionResult CreateNewItem() {

            CreateNewItemViewModel viewModel = new CreateNewItemViewModel()
            {
               EnableListingEmployee = true, 
               EnableListingDealer = true,
               ...
            };
            return View(viewModel);
      }

      [HttpPost]
      public ActionResult CreateNewItem(CreateNewItemViewModelviewModel viewModel) {
        ...
      }
```

**View**

```
   <!-- Employee Enable Listing -->
   <tr class="optionYes">
     <td class="DisplayFieldName">
       @Html.LabelFor(m => m.EnableListingEmployee)
     </td>
     <td class="DisplayFieldData">
       @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EnableListingEmployee, new[] 
                            { new SelectListItem { Text = "Yes", Value = "true" },
                              new SelectListItem {Text = "No", Value = "false" } },"Select.....",
                              new { @Name = "EmployeeEnableListing", @id = "EmployeeEnableListing", style = "width:207px;font-size:10pt;" })                            
      </td>
   </tr>
```

Dealer is the same just Dealer In the place of Employee.

**ViewModel**

```
[Display(Name = "Enable Listing")]
public bool EnableListingEmployee { get; set; }
```

I think that is everything, let me know if we need to see anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because of the following piece of code:

```
 new { @Name = "EmployeeEnableListing"
```

as you have changed the name attribute of the dropdownlist the mvc model binder is unable to populate the `EnableListingEmployee` property when the form is posted. As the mvc binds the input element's name property to the Model object property on the form post.

Currently it is posting as `false` as it is the default value of `bool` which means the value is not actually posting.

You need to remove this explicity name specifying to make it work.

Something like:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.EnableListingEmployee, new[] 
                        { 
                          new SelectListItem { Text = "Yes", Value = "true" },
                          new SelectListItem {Text = "No", Value = "false" } 
                        },
                        "Select.....",
                        new 
                        { 
                            id = "EmployeeEnableListing", 
                            style = "width:207px;font-size:10pt;" 
                        }
                      )
```

Comment: would it also work if i changed the `@Name` attribute to match what the model is? `EnableListingEmployee `

Comment: @whisk yes it should